# having some issue with swfobject.js version 1.5

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

Good day!  I have some issue with swfobject.js version 1.5 in IE7 and IE8.. My chart doesn't display in my web browser.. But when i used a different browser like chrome, firefox and IE 6 it worked perfectly.. Just want to ask, if you have any suggestion to resolve this issue..?

```
here's my code.. BTW, 'm using asp classic 

var so = new SWFObject("flash/graph.swf", "graph", "500", "500", "7", "#ffffff");
so.addVariable("postURL", "ChartProject.asp?ID=<%=ID%>*<%=analysis%>");
so.addVariable("quality", "high");
so.addVariable("salign", "TL");
so.addVariable("graphVersion", "true");

so.write("flashcontent");
```

Hope to hear from you soon..

Thanks,

Link

Answer (score 0):

See the same web page in firefox/chrome or safari. They all have javascript console which will guide you locating the offending line.

For chrome > tools > javascript console.

Since your issue is on the client side, it has nothing to do with ASP.

Comment: resolved issue by adding this line of code Response.CacheControl = "no-store"